# How to rename a project in Xcode?

Tags: xcode4, project

There are some pretty horrible instructions out there for [renaming projects](http://aplus.rs/programming/how-to-rename-project-in-xcode-3x/) in Xcode. Is there no easy way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**In Xcode 4 try this:**

⌘+1, click the blue node with the project name, wait a second, click again (the name becomes editable). That's it.

Answer (score 4):

In the menu bar choose `Project -> Rename...`

It'll do all the hard work for you and rename everything that needs renaming apart from the folder that the project is in.

Comment: Great, simpler than I thought.

Comment: I Renamed and also moved my project. One issue I noticed is that I lost my Snapshots (well they may still be around on filesystem, but XCode doesn't recognize them for the renamed/moved project). Not sure if the loss of Snapshots was due to rename or move operation.

Comment: In my Xcode 4 this opition is grayed out (disabled). What to do?

Answer (score 4):

In XCode 4, select the project name at the top of the documents list on the left and hit enter, rename it, and then XCode will show you a list of files that will be altered, as well as allowing you to take a snapshot.

Comment: good answer but a bit late to the punch :) Thanks anyway, though.